# How to skip WebDriverWait if it is not True?

Tags: python, selenium, bots, instagram

A bit bad in English. I am just making a simple Instagram bot that first takes usernames and passwords from the txt file and put it to login in the website, But "Turn on Notification" pop up only in the first login. Whenever bot login with the second account it does not pop up. I want my WebdriverWait to ignore if it does not find any element. I want it to ignore if "Turn on Notification" does not pop up in other accounts.

My code to remove Turn on Notification pop up:

```
pop_up = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".aOOlW.HoLwm"))).click() # Remove notification
sleep(4)
```

My whole code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from getpass import getpass

from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


# Create a list of username, password pairs from your file.
username_password_list = list()
with open("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\PyCharmCE2020.1\\scratches\\detail.txt") as file:
 for line in file:
   user, password = line.split(':')
   username_password_list.append((user, password))

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Runs Firefox.
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/') # Web address to load.

for user, password in username_password_list:
class Main:
    username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="username"]') # Finds username field.
    password_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="password"]') # Finds password field.

    username_input.send_keys(user) # Input username.
    password_input.send_keys(password) # Input password.

    login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]') # Finds login button.
    login_button.click() # Click login button.

    pop_up = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".aOOlW.HoLwm"))).click() # Remove notification.
    sleep(4)

class SearchBar:
    Search = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@class, "XTCLo x3qfX")]') # Find search bar.
    Search.send_keys("Any_Username") # Input.
    browser.find_element_by_class_name("yCE8d").click() # Search.
    sleep(5)

    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="vBF20 _1OSdk"]').click() # Finds follow button and click.
    sleep(5)

class Logout:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[5]').click() # Go to profile.
    sleep(5)

    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div/button').click() # Click settings.
    sleep(5)

    browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/button[9]').click() # Click logout.
    sleep(5)

browser.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `try/except` block:

```
try:

    ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".piCib")))
    ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".aOOlW.HoLwm"))).click()
except:

    pass
```

`except` block will be executed after a 5-sec timeout when there is no pop-up.

I hope it helps you!

Comment: I tried but didn't work. I tried it in the loop and outside the loop.

Comment: @Maxcillius, why are you using `class`-declarations inside the loop?

Comment: @Maxcillius, remove them, they are not needed there.

Comment: I removed all class and put all process inside for loop but still, it didn't work. showing error                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                          Element <a class="yCE8d  " href="/Any_Username/"> is not clickable at point (675,93) because another element <div class="RnEpo Yx5HN    "> obscures it

Comment: @Maxcillius, try to use explicit wait for pop-up visibility and then use my code in answer. It should work. Thanks.

Comment: @Maxcillius, I have updated my answer. Check it out, please. Thanks.

Comment: It did pass first account notification but with the second account, the notification didn't pop up and it got stuck there.

Comment: File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 38, in <module>
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".piCib")))

Comment: File "C:\Users\user\Documents\InstaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @Maxcillius, yes, it's my fault, sorry. The first line should be under the `try`-block. I have updated my answer again.